# Use column value in M Query / Power Query

Tags: soap, powerbi, powerquery

I've a short code to make a SOAP request to fetch data into Power BI. The problem is that I need to give a Session_id for the requests:

```
let
SourceURL = "HTTPS://SOAP.E-BOEKHOUDEN.NL/SOAP.ASMX?WSDL", //host provides this address. Url ends often with "wsdl"

options = [ #"Authorization" ="Basic USER:PASS=", //User:pass decoded with SOAP UI
            #"Accept-Encoding"= "gzip,deflate",
           // SOAPAction="", 
            #"Content-Type"="text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
            #"Connection"="Keep-Alive"
          ],
WebContent = Web.Contents(SourceURL, 
// Content options in Web.Contents() requires you to authenticate anonymously ! 
    [Content=Text.ToBinary("
    
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:soap1=""http://www.e-boekhouden.nl/soap"">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:OpenSession>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:Username>***</soap1:Username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:SecurityCode1>***</soap1:SecurityCode1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:SecurityCode2>***</soap1:SecurityCode2>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:Source></soap1:Source>
      </soap1:OpenSession>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

"), 
Headers=options]) ,
XmlContent = Xml.Tables(WebContent)
in
 XmlContent
```

Now this code is to get the Session_id. To get the other data I need to give the session_id instead of *SecurityCode2* in a similar request:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://www.e-boekhouden.nl/soap">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:GetMutaties>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:SessionID>***</soap:SessionID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:SecurityCode1>***</soap:SecurityCode1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:cFilter>
            
         </soap:cFilter>
      </soap:GetMutaties>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can I use a column value as parameter/variable that I can use in the body?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a column for that. Create a query that just returns a string:

[image]

and then you can reference that query anywhere else:

[image]